# about &(bit and) operator

Tags: java, algorithm, math

I hava see this code in HashMap:

```
/**
 * Returns index for hash code h.
 */
static int indexFor(int h, int length) {
    // assert Integer.bitCount(length) == 1 : "length must be a non-zero power of 2";
    return h & (length-1);
}
```

The HashMap has this document:
      **when length is a power of two then h & (length-1) is equals h%length**

I want to know the principle in math
just is why h & (length-1) == h%length (length is a power of two)

Comment: In decimal, 10^n = 100000000…; 10^n - 1 = 9999999…. Same principle.

Comment: can you detailed explanation to me ? i'm still confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can think what it looks like when you take any integer `n` mod power of 2.

---

WLOG let this power of 2 is `10000` in binary (indeed it must be of the form `100...0`), what does its multiples looks like? Its multiples must look like`...whatever digit...0000`.  The last 4 digit must be zero.

So what is a number `n mod 10000`? Let this number `n` be `...whatever digit...1011`. This number can be expressed as `...whatever digit...0000 + 1011`, now it is obvious that `n mod 10000` indeed only the last 4 digits is left.

***In general, let `length` be a power of 2 which has `x` zeros, then `n%length` is the least `x` significant digits of `n`***

---

So `legnth - 1`is indeed `111..111` (`x`  digit 1), and when you take bitwise and with the number `n`, the least `x` significant digits of `n` is preserved and returned, which is what we want. Using the same example above,

```
Length = 10000, Length - 1 = 1111
n = 101001101 = 101000000 + 1101
=> n % Length = 1101

n & (Length - 1) = 1101
= n % Length
```

Answer (score 0):

Just imagine: any power of two contains single bit set and has binary representation like this:

```
      l = 00010000
```

if you subtract 1, it will contain ones at the right places

```
    m = l-1 = 00001111
```

binary AND operation with any h makes all most significant bits zero, leaving less significant ones

```
     10101010  & 00001111 = 00001010
```

This is equivalent to modulo operation with modulo l